# Custom AlertDialog with cut off corners

Tags: android

I need to have a custom AlertDialog with cut off corners, please check the attached image. The image isn't static but a transparent and I need to fill it with some color. What approach should I take in order to construct such a layout? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: You need to take an image and set it as a background resource for your inflated view of `AlertDialog`

Comment: I need to fill this black area with a custom color, how can I keep the corners aside from filling?

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Create a `transparent 9-Patch` `.png image` with cut edges like your image. Use the image background color same as you want on your `Alert Dialog`

**2.**  Now create a `custom layout` for your dialog using this image.

**3.**  Now use this custom layout in your `Custom Alert Dialog.`

**4.** Now as `Brajendra` said use this code :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SettingActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);
```

Here `dialog_main` is the layout which you created using your image with cut edges.

Comment: Can you please clarify how to prevent those cut corners from filling? If I set background for the image - the whole area dedicated for the image would be filled, not the only `src` I define.

Comment: In your image just make those corners Transparent and save this image in .png format with transparency. Now use this image as background you will automatically have transparent corner like you want. Yes the corners will fill with image but that part of image will be transparent so it will look like the way you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a 9 patch image. then create custom layout for Create this type of dialog. Suppose your dialog layout is dialog_main...
Then create dialog from following code...

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SettingActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to fill the black area with some color, how to fill it the way so cut off corners are still transparent?

Comment: You can create a layout with a background image like you have with the 9 patch limiters and they will do.

Comment: What limiters are you about?